# Problems with displaying values of a property

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to display the values of a book in `myLibrary` but the when I do it displays it like this :

- Zero To one
- Peter Thiel
- 210
- Has been read already
- function() { return title + " " + "by" + " " + author + " " + pages + " " + "pages" + " " + isRead; }

It shouldn't display this part:

```
function() { return title + " " + "by" + " " + author + " " + pages + " " + "pages" + " " + isRead; }
```

Here's my code:

```
    this.pages = pages;
    this.isRead = isRead;
    this.info = function() {
        return title + " " + "by" + " " + author + " " + pages + " " + "pages" + " " + isRead;
    }
}

const zeroToOne = new Book("Zero To one", "Peter Thiel", "210", "Has been read already");

function addBookToLibrary(bookToAdd) {
    myLibrary.push(bookToAdd);
    console.log(myLibrary);
    for (let obj of myLibrary) {
        console.log(obj);
        card.textContent = Object.values(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't see your `constructor` and where you call `this.info`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `info` function :

```
console.log(obj.info());
```